# Using jsoup for extracting attributes from "a" inside "span" inside "class" for sports software

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I´ve been reading all the questions i could find regarding jsoup and attributes, classes, spans and so on.. But none could help me get this data from this website.

I am working on some sports software and retrieve match-data from the site soccer24.com
 and now i want to get more data from specific match pages(win-lose history)

so i need either the last scores, or whats even better the "win" or "lose" result

the scores are written like this:

```
<td class="" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="score"><strong>2 : 1</strong></span></td>
```

here i could work with the "2:1"

this is what i try right now:

```
Elements wl =docl.select("span.score");
                            System.out.println(wl);
                        for(Element w :wl){

                                            System.out.println(w.ownText());

                                        }
```

the result is written like this:

```
<td class="winLose" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="winLoseIcon"><a title="Win" class="form-bg-last form-w"><span></span></a></span></td>
```

here i would need the "win" from the a title

ive really tried everything but cant extract it.. would be really grateful for any help.....  and before i make it another question... i would also need the odds-movement..
i get the final odds but the movements are written like this:

```
<span class="up" alt="1.73[u]1.75">1.75</span>
```

so the "alt" attribute

if i could get all these things would be awesome and i know its not a big deal for u , but ive been trying around for hours now and this is really my last resort

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract attribute from an element ? If so,

**EDIT:**
Now it seems your real issue is not JSOUP parsing, but getting the content.

The link contains #h2h;overall. means it is not getting actual response from server, but it makes ajax request after it loads the page, to another url(http://d.soccer24.com/x/feed/d_hh_K2AUJ0ih_en_2)

When I checked the response, I found that it repetitively makes calls to server and updates the result. This request and response both are encrypted. Following updated code should display you correct results.

```
// ** Test Data
//Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><h1></h1><table>"
//          + "<td class=\"winLose\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\"><span class=\"winLoseIcon\"><a title=\"Win\" class=\"form-bg-last form-w\"><span></span></a></span></td>"
//          + "<span class=\"up\" alt=\"1.73[u]1.75\">1.75</span>" + "</table>/</body></html>");
//
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://d.soccer24.com/x/feed/d_hh_K2AUJ0ih_en_2");
    con.header("X-Fsign", "SW9D1eZo");
    Document doc = con.get();
//Your code
Elements elems=doc.select("td.winLose > span.winLoseIcon > a[title]");
for(Element elem:elems){
    System.out.println(elem.attr("title"));
}
```

Similarly for odds:

```
Elements elems=doc.select("span.up[alt]"); 
for(Element elem:elems) println( elem.attr("alt"));
```

RESULT:

```
..Lots of lines Win | Lose | Draw..
```

Comment: hey man, thank u very much but i dont get any output. only empty strings :/

Comment: i think i know why.. i try to connect to the link of the match and then add the part for the head to head page.. but it doesnt take me there.. although the link is correct , it stays on the main match centre page.. starnge

Comment: I just tested my code with test data, it is printing desired result. Not sure what are you taking about links and head page, center page ?

Comment: hey , :) yea your code should work.. i dont know how to explain, maybe you can check out the site soccer24.com, click on a match, a new window opens.. i manage to get this link from the main table.. in this window you can click H2H.. the site than switches to the H2H page and in the address line u can see that this page has its own link (http://www.soccer24.com/match/K2AUJ0ih/#h2h;overall) something like this... now when i parse this link i would hope to get the content of the head to head page but when i print out the jsoup document ,

Comment: the result is the content of the "match centre" page.. not the "H2H" page.. any idea how i can navigate to this div?

Comment: now i try to print the "H2H" div but this is the output:<div id="tab-match-head-2-head" style="display: none;"> 
 <div id="head-2-head-preload" class="preload-panel">
  <div class="preload">
   <span>Loading ...</span>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: I updated answer with actual ajax url it uses to get data.

Comment: thats awesome :) thank you verrry much..  now i select the table for the hometeam, take first five or six elements and move to awayteam , do the same and move to next game...   You are the man , MAN :)

Comment: hey man, its me again...  your answer was superb and now i wonder if you could help me again..  i get that i use this d.soccer24.com feed.. can u tell me how i can navigate in there?  like if want to open not the head2head page but the odds comparison for example.. or the standings page.. that would be awesome :)